# How do I create a django project on my D: drive?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and django and wanted to create a django project on my D drive. However, in order to create the django project I have to do it through the terminal and it seems to automatically create the django project in my C drive. How can I change that location?

Comment: Use `django-admin startproject path/to/D-Drive/mysite` or just cut and paste the project

Answer (score 0):

go to your D drive . Create A Folder . Name it as you want .
Then open this folder in Pycharm. and follow this commands

```
1. pip install virtualenv (for windows user)
2. virtualenv myenv (myenv is your virtual environment name. You can give anything as you want)
3.  .\myenv\scripts\activate (activate virtualenv)
4. pip install django==2.2.10
5. django-admin startproject dj (dj is the project name. You can give anything)
6. cd dj
7. python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

*You can follow the following steps

1. 1.Open your command prompt
2. .Run the following commands step by step by pressing enter:
3. a. D: (This will take you to your D drive)

b. mkdir Django-Project (This
will make a folder in D drive)

c. cd Django-Project

d. django-admin
startproject project1 (This will create a project name project
inside Django-Project)